# Blogger Fb Comments Box

Tags: blogger

Okay, I have successfully added fb comment box for each of my blogger posts, but the problem is that I only want that comment box to show on the post page itself but not on the home page. I have searched but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Enclose your current code of the Facebook Comment Box like this:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>

   ...your fb-comment-box code...

</b:if>
```